# How to Make a FULL Yocto eSDK Sysroot to Do CMake Cross-Compilation?

Tags: cross-compiling, yocto, openembedded, imx6

I'm trying to cross-compile CMake/C++ projects to be deployed onto Variscite's SoM i.MX6 DART board. They use Yocto with Freescale Linux (hence the `fsl-image-gui` you'll see below). I've been reading up on eSDKs and have been confused/stuck on a problem for a while. Here's the problem... How do I get a **full/non-partial** Yocto eSDK sysroot+toolchain so I can do CMake cross-compilation with it? Other SO posts have gotten me part of the way there, supplying several commands that you'll see below, but the sysroot is still not **full**. Here's what I'm trying to do...

First, I run these commands:

```sh
# Following http://variwiki.com/index.php?title=Yocto_Build_Release&release=RELEASE_THUD_V1.0_VAR-SOM-MX6
mkdir -p ~/bin
curl http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/git-repo-downloads/repo > ~/bin/repo
chmod a+x ~/bin/repo
export PATH=~/bin:$PATH
mkdir ~/var-fslc-yocto
cd ~/var-fslc-yocto
repo init -u https://github.com/varigit/variscite-bsp-platform.git -b thud
repo sync -j4
MACHINE=var-som-mx6 DISTRO=fslc-framebuffer . setup-environment build_fb
echo 'TOOLCHAIN_HOST_TASK_append = "${SDK_EXTRA_TOOLS}"' >> conf/local.conf
echo 'SDK_EXTRA_TOOLS = " nativesdk-cmake     "' >> conf/local.conf
bitbake fsl-image-gui
bitbake -c populate_sdk_ext fsl-image-gui
cd tmp/deploy/sdk
./fslc-framebuffer-glibc-x86_64-fsl-image-gui-armv7at2hf-neon-toolchain-ext-2.6.2.sh
# Get a new shell (clears the environment variables set by the "MACHINE ..." command you ran above)
exit
ssh username@ubuntu-machine
cd ~/fslc-framebuffer_sdk
source ./environment-setup-armv7at2hf-neon-fslc-linux-gnueabi
devtool add lcm https://github.com/lcm-proj/lcm/archive/v1.4.0.tar.gz
# Edit the autogenerated recipe in an editor.
# Change the EXTRA_OECMAKE variable line to...
# EXTRA_OECMAKE = "-DLCM_ENABLE_EXAMPLES=OFF -DLCM_ENABLE_TESTS=OFF"
devtool edit-recipe lcm
devtool build lcm
devtool build-image fsl-image-gui
```

Due to the `SDK_EXTRA_TOOLS` and `nativesdk-cmake` lines, the eSDK does indeed have a CMake toolchain file at `~/fslc-framebuffer_sdk/sysroots/x86_64-fslcsdk-linux/usr/share/cmake/OEToolchainConfig.cmake`. That's very helpful. What I want to be able to do is use that toolchain to cross-compile a CMake/C++ project that depends on LCM (it does a `find_package(LCM)`). Unfortunately, since Yocto's Rocko version, it looks like eSDK sysroots don't have all of the recipe installation files (see [this](http://lists.openembedded.org/pipermail/openembedded-architecture/2016-November/000336.html) and [this](https://patchwork.openembedded.org/patch/136198/)). What this means is that each recipe builds with its own sysroot. This means that the `devtool build lcm` makes a recipe-specific sysroot instead of populating the existing `var-som-mx6` sysroot that the `OEToolchainConfig.cmake` file points to (and that I would like to treat as a CMake cross-compilation sysroot). Therefore, the `find_package(LCM)` is failing to find LCM, since the `var-som-mx6` sysroot doesn't have it.

The `var-som-mx6` sysroot already has tons of other utilities installed there like NodeJS, udev, etc. How do I make LCM also get installed there instead of into its own recipe-specific sysroot?

Comment: You need to add `DEPENDS = "lcm"` on your project recipe, and probably need to add `'TOOLCHAIN_TARGET_TASK_append = " lcm-dev"` before generating sdk.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. Should I add `TOOLCHAIN_TARGET_TASK_append = " lcm-dev"` to my `build_fb/conf/local.conf` or somewhere in my LCM recipe?

Comment: in `local.conf`